# How to format the argument of scipy.optimize.fsolve for arrays of data

Tags: python, arrays, scipy-optimize

I'd like to use a solver (scipy.optimize.fsolve) to solve for the root of a function, fun(x,y). In this case, I want the argument (y) to be an array (e.g. an array of data). I would also like to avoid using for-loops to call fsolve for each value in y.

In specifying arg (y) as an array, I am getting an error that the result from the function call is not a proper array of floats. Other errors occur if I make "data" a tuple instead of an array.

Here is an MWE of the problem:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def fun(x, y):
    return x+y

data = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
x = fsolve(fun, x0=0, args=data)
print(x)
```

How can the input to fsolve be corrected so that it solves for the root of fun(x,y) for each value of y in the array (without using a for-loop)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function, that is passed to **fsolve**, takes at least one (possibly vector) argument and returns a value of the same length as mentioned [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html).

In your case, you are passing *x0=0* and *args=np.array([1,2,3,4])* to fsolve. The return value of *fun* has a different length to x0 (x0 is a scalar and args is an array having shape *(4,)*).

The following code solves your problem:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def fun(x, y):
    return x+y

data = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
x = fsolve(fun, x0=np.array([0,0,0,0]), args=data)
print(x)
```